# Panels - simpilfy content management?

Tags: panels

I want to make it easy for web managers to change content in panel layouts. 
I.e. not the layout in itself but specific content.

For view listings in panels, it is quite straight-forward for web managers to add content (just by navigating to the particular content type and "add/modify").

For static content however (like introductions to a particular page), I am not sure what the best alternative is?

**Example:**
Let us say I create a panel page "FAQ" which should look something like this:

> ## FAQ
>
> "Pane 1"
>   On this page you find answers to some of the most
>   frequently asked questions ...
>
> "Pane 2"
>   Q: Bla bla
>   A: Bla bla
>
> "Pane 3"
>   Links to other parts of the webpage block

In this example, how would you set up the intro text ("On this page ...") so that editors can easily tweak it? Is it a content type, a block, custom non-reusable content or what is it?

Comment: I would suggest a block ..

Comment: So I should teach the editors to go into blocks, find the right region (content in this case) and then edit the block? Sounds quite counter-intuitive? Wouldn't it be better if they could find the content by name of the page? I.e. I want to edit FAQ, so I go to the FAQ panel page or FAQ piece of content ...?